# Log level of file handler vs. that of logger

Tags: python, logging

To set up logging in Python *without* `basicConfig` we would go through the steps:

1. Set up a file handler.
2. Set the logging level of the file handler.
3. Set up a formatter.
4. Point the file handler to the formatter.
5. Get the logger object.
6. Set the logging level of the logger object.
7. Add the file handler as a handler to the logger object.
8. Use the `.info()`, `.warning()`, etc method on the logger.

These steps are executed by the following code:

```
import logging

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('./out.log', 'a')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

format_string = '%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(format_string)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)

logger.info('visible info')
logger.debug('invisible debug')
```

What is the difference between setting the logging level for the file handler and setting the logging level for the logger?

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework or interview question.

Comment: Regarding your edit - a single file handler can be used by many loggers, hence the ability to set different levels. For example if you set the file handler to only accept `logger.ERROR`, but you want any logger to use that file (say it's a global error log) - then you can have each logger using it's own logging level while redirecting all errors to that file. Would you like me to post that as an answer and add an example?

Comment: @KacperFloriański Let me ask a second question, since you're telling me (yet) something else I don't know.

Comment: @KacperFloriański Could you add your comment as an answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/57813749/704972 question, while elaborating, if possible, on the object diagram?

Comment: I will have an in-depth look tomorrow but it looks logically correct at first glance. The file handlers could technically point to the same file (but you wouldnt normally do that), and I think Python logging only provides 4 levels (debug, info, warning and error). I will post an example here which will hopefully answer your third question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so here is a small bit of code to work out:

```
import logging


# Declare a function to log all 5 levels with different information
def log_all_levels(logger):
    logger.debug("Debug from logger {}".format(logger.name))
    logger.info("Info from logger {}".format(logger.name))
    logger.warning("Warning from logger {}".format(logger.name))
    logger.error("Error from logger {}".format(logger.name))
    logger.critical("Fatal from logger {}".format(logger.name))


# This file handler will track errors from all loggers
all_errors_handler = logging.FileHandler('errors.log')
all_errors_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# This file handler will only be used in a specific region of code
foo_info_handler = logging.FileHandler('foo_info.log')
foo_info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
foo_info_handler.addFilter(lambda r: r.levelno == logging.INFO)

# The following loggers will be used in the main execution
foo_logger = logging.getLogger("Foo")
nameless_logger = logging.getLogger("nameless")
foo_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
nameless_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
loggers = (foo_logger, nameless_logger)

# Set each logger up to use the file handlers
# Each logger can have many handlers, each handler can be used by many loggers
for logger in loggers:
    logger.addHandler(all_errors_handler)
    debug_file_handler = logging.FileHandler('{}.log'.format(logger.name))
    debug_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(debug_file_handler)
    if logger.name == "Foo":
        logger.addHandler(foo_info_handler)


# Let's run some logging operations
for logger in loggers:
    log_all_levels(logger)
```

There are 2 loggers - `foo_logger` set to the info level and `nameless_logger` set to the debug level. Both of them use the errors and debug handlers, however only the `foo_logger` uses the `foo_file_handler`. There are now loggers and file handlers with different levels, connected together in a many-to-many relationship.

As you can find out:

1. `errors.log` will contain errors from both loggers. Quite self-explanatory for a real life scenario - reading through logs containing just the errors helps debugging the code.
2. `Foo.log` and `nameless.log` will contain everything possible about those loggers, respecting their levels. So the former will contain info and greater, whereas the latter will track debug and greater levels. Logging per object will potentially create a lot of files, but it might be crucial when trying to detect some object-specific errors.
3. `foo_info` is a very special file handler and it **only** allows info level from the associated logger. Such files can be a life saver when you enter a potentially unsafe or untested area of code and would like to see what exactly is happening within that code block, without having to browse through all your program log.

There are many other things you can do with logging - set up your own logging rules, make a logging hierarchy, create a logger factory - possibilities are endless. Logging should allow flexibility - for example by allowing logger objects and file handlers to have different and separate logging levels, and letting the programmer combine them together as needed.

I hope the small code exercise alongside with my explanations cleared any further doubts - but I do recommend to have a look at [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) or the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) if you still need more examples.