# Understanding Python logging through an object diagram

Tags: python, logging

The diagram shows the object diagram for setting up Python logging objects. Once the logger objects are set, the ongoing program will interact with just the (three) logger objects.

In this object diagram, proper objects are shown with a white background. Scalars are shown with a yellow background. The arrows are a pointer, or a setting. Hence the arrow from the left file handler to the top left file handler log level signal that the latter is a parameter to the former.

[image: logging object diagram]

A: Loggers 2 and 3 share the same file handler, hence their output will mix (by timestamp).

B: Logger 1 uses a different file handler, hence it will have its own output file.

C: There are potentially five different log levels involved for this object diagram.

Are these three statements correct?

Comment: I don't understand this diagram.  Why do the file handlers flow into log levels?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: @JohnGordon I added a description of the arrows in the diagram to the body of the question.

Comment: @KlausD. No, it's not. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57813067/704972

Comment: I still don't understand.  Log levels are associated with _loggers_, not _handlers_.  The logger objects in the diagram are already connected to log levels.  Why are the file handler objects _also_ connected to (different) log levels?

Comment: The words you are using have nothing to do with the Python language and the typical phrases used with it. It is confusing at its best.

Comment: @JohnGordon I think you're wrong. The documentation https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging shows that a distinct log level can be set for a stream handler: `ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`, hence it would appear that a distinct log level can be set (also tried it) for a file handler. But please correct me if you understand this better than I do.

Comment: @JohnGordon You can set the logging level of a file handler. In fact I think you have it backwards. Loggers have handlers (that are set at different log levels).

Comment: @KlausD. Could you be specific? Which words are ambiguous or not quite pythonic?

Comment: The only confusing part of your post is the arrows, which are typically used in UML to show inheritance, not attributes, and typically attributes point in the other direction. Otherwise I totally understand your questions.

Comment: @alkasm I stand corrected!  I wasn't aware that handlers could have levels of their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three statements are correct, the third is a little weird though.

> A: Loggers 2 and 3 share the same file handler, hence their output will mix (by timestamp).

Note that loggers 2 and 3 could have additional handlers, they could share more or have their own. Each logger can have multiple handlers.

> B: Logger 1 uses a different file handler, hence it will have its own output file.

One logger, one handler, one output file. Easy to understand.

> C: There are potentially five different log levels involved for this object diagram.

True, but the three levels associated with each logger do something different than the levels associated with the handlers. The levels on each logger tell the logger to entirely ignore all messages below that level. So for instance, if you have a handler that handles DEBUG messages, but that is on a logger with INFO set as the level, the handler will never send DEBUG messages from that specific logger. So, the logger will take all messages at or above the logger level, and forward them off to each handler it has. Check the following flow diagram [from the Python logging advanced tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial):

[image: Logging diagram]

The diagram is pretty self explanatory, so I won't rehash it too much. But this should hopefully clear all your doubts.